# rounded rectangle around every word iPhone

Tags: iphone, view, background, label

I have to create a rounded rectangle around every word of a label like this:
[image: tag]
Can I use a method like `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` or can I set it as a background view?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it on a word-by-word basis easily.  I would create a parent view, then split the text into words and add a label for each.  Your stretchable image approach would work for the individual labels then.

Comment: yes, my string is only one word... I tried this code but it doesn't work... http://pastebin.com/UaCUPd71

Answer (score 0):

Stretching an image would led you to an ugly rendering especially if you have very long word.
I would process like this :

Create this hierarchy :

```
- UIView theView
-- UIView imagesView
--- UIImageView startBackgroundImage
--- UIImageView endBackgroundImage
-- UILabel theLabel
```

theView will be the view containing your label and the background images, theLabel will contain the label itself, and imagesView contains all the image views you will need.

So first we will set the text of the label and get the size of the string :

```
theLabel.text = @"Food";
theLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"content.png"]];
CGSize textSize = [[theLabel text] sizeWithFont:[theLabel font]];
```

Finally, we will set the size of theView (imagesView will have the same size) and the position of startBackgroundImage and endBackgroundImage.

```
int height = startBackgroundImage.image.size.height;

int startBackgroundImageWidth = startBackgroundImage.image.size.width;
int endBackgroundImageWidth = endBackgroundImage.image.size.width;
theView.frame = CGRectMake(xYouWant,yYoutWant,textSize.width+startBackgroundImageWidth+endBackgroundImageWidth,height);
startBackgroundImage.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,startBackgroundImage.frame.width,startBackgroundImage.frame.height);
endBackgroundImage.frame = CGRectMake(textSize.width+endBackgroundImageWidth,0,endBackgroundImage.frame.width,endBackgroundImage.frame.height);
```

Can't upload image so I will try to describe :
startBackgroundImage will contain the left of the image (rounded)
endBackgroundImage will contain the right of the image (rounded)
And content.png will contain an image of few pixel wide, that will be used as a pattern.

Comment: Stretching the image doesn't give ugly results if the image is created with stretching in mind and the cap is correctly defined - this is how most buttons on the iPhone are created. There is a 1px section in the centre of the image that can be repeated for the length of the stretch.

Comment: Yes, and a more flexible version (resizableImageWithCapInsets:) is present instead.